# to show visited color on javascript link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a hyperlink which is calling the JavaScript function. My link renders as follows

```
<a class="popup" onclick="return launchModalNews('http://google.com',this)" href="http://google.com/">google</a>
```

In my JavaScript I am opening this link as popup and I return `false` so that I don't navigate away from page.

Due to this my link doesn't show as visited.

To show as visited I have create a hidden `iframe` and I am setting the `src` on the link click so that IE maintains the history.

This works fine and IE is able to show the link as visited but the issue is that now when I try to check whether the link is visited or not I am not getting proper color.

I have used following ways:

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).color 
jQuery(element).css('color');
```

this all give the normal link color not the visited one while In page I can see  that it has applied the visited link color how can I get the real color i.e. visited color using jquery/javascript?

Secondly this method for showing visited link works in IE but not in chrome.Is there any idea how to achieve this on chrome?

[Update to the replies]
First of all this is not google.com this is another link.i just gave an example
secondly If I add class at runtime then it works fine for that scenario but once the page refreshes then I don't get the visited links and I will not able to add the custom class.
I have tried "a:visted" in jquery but it returns 0 items.I want to check the color so that I can optimise it.
If I get the color as visited then I will not set the src for iframe because that link is already in browser history and the browser take care of the visited link

Comment: Can't you just use the `target="_blank"` attribute to open it in a new tab instead? Why do you want to open google in popup?

Comment: You cannot fetch the visited state of an anchor by trying to detect color==a:visited - This was considered a security issue (arbitrarily detecting a visitors site history) and modern browsers will fall back to the default color.

Comment: just simply add a class to the **a** tag when clicked and then define the css for that class as you want

Comment: Can't you just define a css style for a:active? (see [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes))

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class (which is styled in the same way as actual visited links) when you click your link:

```
$('.popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    launchModalNews('http://google.com',this);
    $(this).addClass('visited');
});
```